# Using Javascript to create a wildcard link

Tags: javascript, html

Struggling with making a wildcard link with JavaScript and in general using JavaScript to create links. Would love to store my html links in JavaScript and push them into the html while being able to make them dynamic links.

Basically I have a lot of documents I'm linking from SharePoint for easier access to my team at work. My boss want's them to be wildcard links, dynamic as opposed to static, and I'm really struggling as being a relative noob at JavaScript.

This is an example of the HTML I'm working on.

```
<h2>Quality Management Key Documents</h2>
<div class="dropdown">
     <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="dropbtn">Corporate Manual Policies and User Manual</button>
      <div id="Corporate Manual Policies" class="dropdown-content">
**<!--This is the example/practice version-->**   <button onclick =  "link()" class="page-header">Works?</button>
          <a href="javascript:getURL()">Derpalot</a>
    </div>
```

And this is the JavaScript Code I'm trying to work with.

```
var links = [];
links[0] = "link",
"Corporate Quality Manual"; //etc in terms of links

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute(link);
link.innerHTML = desiredText;

function linkA() {
document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].innerHTML += '<a href="'links[0]'">' + links[0] + '</a>';
};
```

Comment: You are not using setAttribute correctly. It takes two arguments. The first is the name of the attribute as a string, and the second is the value of the attributes as a string. You are setting the name of the attribute to the link object that you are actually trying to set the attribute of and you are not passing a second argument at all

Comment: oh thanks! makes more sense to me.

Comment: Why are you creating a [`<link>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), it seems - from the description/text of your question - that you should be creating [`<a>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)?

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Also - Given that I am using links from Sharepoint is the sharepoint SDK/API worthwhile using for this task? Specifically for creating dynamic links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of worrying about `setAttribute` and `innerHTML`, you can use the shortcut properties `anchor.href = url` and `anchor.textContent = text`.

I created a function `update()` that will take all of the information from the variable `links` and render it inside your container. I figured you might want to customize link text, so I made the array into a list of `[href, text]` pairs.

Every time you want to change the links that are on the page, you can edit your `links` array and then call `update()` when you are done, which will push all of your changes to the DOM.

```
links.push(['https://new-link.com', 'New Link Text'])
update()
```

Let me know if you'd like me to explain any particular section of the code in more detail.

**Demo:**

```js
var links = [
  ['https://example.com', 'Example Text'],
  ['https://stackoverflow.com', 'StackOverflow']
]

function update () {
  var container = document.getElementById('corporate-manual-policies'),
      anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a'),
      length = anchors.length,
      i = 0
  // Re-use current anchors if possible, adjusting their `href` and `textContent`
  while (i < anchors.length) {
    anchors[i].href = links[i][0]
    anchors[i].textContent = links[i][1]
    i++
  }
  // Create new anchors if necessary
  i = length
  length = links.length
  while (i < length) {
    container.appendChild(
      anchor(links[i][0], links[i][1])
    )
    i++
  }
  
}

function anchor(href, text) {
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = href
  a.textContent = text
  return a
}
```

```html
<h2>Quality Management Key Documents</h2>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="dropbtn">Corporate Manual Policies and User Manual</button>
  <div id="corporate-manual-policies" class="dropdown-content">
    **
    <!--This is the example/practice version-->**
    <button onclick="update()" class="page-header">Update Links</button>
    <a href="javascript:getURL()">Derpalot</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is top notch stuff. I'm going to implement it and then I'd appreciate some questions so I can understand it on a deeper level. Thanks Gyre!

Comment: Glad I could help. Just reply here with those questions whenever, and I'll respond when I receive that ping notification.

Comment: Currently trying to get it to work. Copied the Javascript accross but I think the html side is not working. 

I think it's something to do with how I'm using the functions in Javascript! See how I can fix it up now.

Comment: Seems like there's no ; added. Currently trying to see if adding it helps

Comment: Would love some extra help Gyre :)

Comment: Sure. Could you post all of your other code, else it's hard to debug by guessing. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would do well enough.

Comment: Cheers! One second I'll post it here

Comment: I think I am a bit confused by your usage. Do you want multiple links for each `h2`, or a single `h2` and all that other HTML for each link? And what exactly are all of those User Manual buttons supposed to do?

Comment: So the idea is to have a button that drop's down a menu of links to documents.

Comment: Several buttons throughout the page for different things like engineering reports and etc

Comment: And these document links ideally are dynamic, so noone has to edit the code later as the files are updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: So - Multiple links for each h2.

The user Manuals are supposed to link to documents contained in sharepoint

Comment: Thanks Gyre - Well I thought using Javascript to push the links into Html would allow me to make them dynamic easier.

Comment: My thought process is step one, be able to push links through javascript, step two, make links dynamic in javascript.

Comment: By Dynamic I mean the link, or href?, will work regardless of small title updates. I.E, the document name has a change from v1.01 to v1.012.

Comment: If your links are changing, **you must have some way to get the new link URL** in order to create anything clickable, even with JS. For example, if your link goes from `http://example.com/documents/Cool-Doc-v1` to `http://example.com/documents/Cool-Doc-v2`, you have to update your code or have some API that knows when the link has changed for any strategy like this to work.

Comment: Oh damn......

So there isn't a way of taking a few values for a certain numeral?

Comment: I would have imagined something like http://example.com/documents/Cool-Doc-xx where anything in xx was acceptable or it searched withing a range between 1-100?

Comment: The best you could do would be to "guess" a version number and load every page URL until you get a successful response. I don't think that is practical or very fair to your users' computers. Sorry to break it to you :(

Comment: Alternatively I can use sharepoint API to try and make it work. I'm taking the links off of sharepoint

Comment: How are you being expected to link to something if you don't know what you are linking to? If there is any sort of "feed" or API that will let you query the latest file names/URLs, I could solve your problems with that. Maybe poke around Sharepoint and see if you can find anything like that, then get back to me later.

Comment: The API needs to be programmatic though, like some sort of `.txt` or `.json` file.

Comment: Thanks Gyre - will have a look now

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach, note that I've removed all in-line event-handlers from the various elements (the `onclick` attributes), and called the function to run once the DOM is ready, rather than requiring the user to click a `<button>` to call the function:

```
// defining a named function, to which an 'opts'
// Object can be passed:
// 'linkSelector'     : String, a CSS selector that can be used
//                      to select the appropriate elements;
// 'ancestorSelector' : String, a CSS selector that can be used
//                      to match the appropriate ancestor, from
//                      which the linkMap property can be retrieved
//                      which holds the details/properties of the
//                      <a> elements;
// 'linkMap'          : Object, with property-values matching the 'id'
//                      of the found ancestor elements, which holds
//                      the details ('text' and 'href') to be assigned
//                      to the <a> elements.
function enableLinks(opts) {

  // the default settings; these can each be overridden by
  // supplying an alternate value for the appropriate
  // property-name in the 'opts' Object:
  let settings = {

       // selects the appropriate elements to manipulate,
       // the default selector finds an <a> element which
       // is an adjacent-sibling of a <button> element
       // with a class of 'page-header':
      'linkSelector': 'button.page-header + a',

      // passed to Element.closest(), and matches the
      // appropriate ancestor - if any - from which
      // the 'id' property-value should be taken in
      // order to retrieve the details of the found <a>;
      // this selector matches a <div> element with an id
      // attribute with a class of 'dropdown-content':
      'ancestorSelector': 'div[id].dropdown-content',

    // an Object containing the relevant details, mapped
    // to the id of the ancestor:
    'linkMap': {

      // id of ancestor element:
      'CorporateManualPolicies': {

        // the 'href' for the link:
        'href': 'http://example.com/corporate/manual/policies',

        // the text-content, and title, of the link:
        'text': 'Link to Corporate Manual Policies.'
      },
      'stackoverflow': {
        'href': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
        'text': 'Link to Stack Overflow.'
      }
    }
  },

    // declared 'empty' variables for use in
    // later loops:
    ancestor,
    cache;

  // iterating over the keys of the 'opts' Object, 
  // or an Object literal (to avoid errors), using
  // Object.keys(), which retrieves the keys of the
  // supplied Object, and returns them as an Array
  // over which we iterate using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(

    // using an Arrow Function:
    // 'key' is a reference to the current 'key'
    // of the Array of keys over which we're iterating;
    // here we set the key of the same name in the
    // 'settings' Object to the property-value held
    // in the opts Object:
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  // using Array.from() to convert the supplied Array-like
  // Object into an Array:
  let foundLinks = Array.from(

        // here we retrieve the non-live NodeList of
        // elements matching the supplied CSS selector
        // from the settings.linkSelector property-value:
        document.querySelectorAll(settings.linkSelector)
      )

  // iterating over that Array of elements, with
  // Array.prototype.filter(), in order to retain only
  // those elements for which the enclosed evaluation
  // returns as true or truthy:
    .filter(function(foundLink) {
      // 'foundLink' a reference to the current element
      // of the Array of elements over which we're iterating.

      // assigning the first - if any - ancestor element of
      // the current element which matches the supplied
      // CSS selector:
      ancestor = foundLink.closest(settings.ancestorSelector);

      // we retain the current element only if
      // 'ancestor' is truthy (not-null) and if the
      // settings.linkMap has a truthy (not-undefined)
      // property-value matching the 'id' property of
      // the ancestor element:
      return ancestor && settings.linkMap[ancestor.id];
    });

  // iterating over the foundLinks Array, using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
  foundLinks.forEach(function(link) {
    // 'link' a reference to the current element in
    // the Array of elements over which we're iterating.

    // as before, finding the first ancestor matching
    // the matching CSS selector (except this time we
    // know there is an ancestor as that was one of the
    // criteria for retaining the elements in the
    // foundLinks Array):
    ancestor = link.closest(settings.ancestorSelector),

    // assigning the Object property-value of the
    // settings.linkMap Object stored in the property
    // of the ancestor's id; again: we know there is
    // a matching property-value as that was the other
    // criteria of retaining the element in the
    // foundLinks Array:
      cache = settings.linkMap[ ancestor.id ];

    // setting the href of the current 'link' element
    // to that held in the 'href' property-value of
    // the cache Object:
    link.href = cache.href;

    // this may be a little confusing, but assigns the
    // link.title property to be equal to the link.textContent
    // property which is itself set to the property-value
    // of the cache.text Object:
    link.title = link.textContent = cache.text;
  });

  // here we return the Array of foundLinks; in order that
  // chaining may take place on those found elements:
  return foundLinks;
}

// here we call the enableLinks function, with no arguments
// so we simply use the default arguments; and we then use
// Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate, again, over the
// the returned Array of elements from the function. Here
// we use an Arrow function to add the 'enabledLink' class-name
// to all <a> elements found within the function (if any):
enableLinks().forEach(el => el.classList.add('enabledLink'));
```

```js
function enableLinks(opts) {
  let settings = {
      'linkSelector': 'button.page-header + a',
      'ancestorSelector': 'div[id].dropdown-content',
      'linkMap': {
        'CorporateManualPolicies': {
          'href': 'http://example.com/corporate/manual/policies',
          'text': 'Link to Corporate Manual Policies.'
        },
        'stackoverflow': {
          'href': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
          'text': 'Link to Stack Overflow.'
        }
      }
    },
    ancestor,
    cache;

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  let foundLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(settings.linkSelector))
    .filter(function(foundLink) {
      ancestor = foundLink.closest(settings.ancestorSelector);
      return ancestor && settings.linkMap[ancestor.id];
    });

  foundLinks.forEach(function(link) {
    ancestor = link.closest(settings.ancestorSelector),
      cache = settings.linkMap[ancestor.id];

    link.href = cache.href;
    link.title = link.textContent = cache.text;
  });

  return foundLinks;
}

enableLinks().forEach(el => el.classList.add('enabledLink'));
```

```css
.enabledLink {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Quality Management Key Documents</h2>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Corporate Manual Policies and User Manual</button>
  <div id="CorporateManualPolicies" class="dropdown-content">
    <button class="page-header">Works?</button>
    <a href="#">Derpalot</a>
  </div>
  <h2>External Resources</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Corporate Manual Policies and User Manual</button>
    <div id="stackoverflow" class="dropdown-content">
      <button class="page-header">Works?</button>
      <a href="#">Derpalot</a>
    </div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jgnxf66j/).

Or, alternatively, since we explicitly use the ancestor elements' `id` property as the property-name of the `settings.linkMap` Object we can instead – using the same HTML as above – simply use that Object to find the appropriate ancestors and iterate over those:

```
// As above, a named function into which an opts Object
// can be passed:
// linkSelector : String, a CSS selector to identify the
//                relevant elements,
// linkMap      : Object, an Object containing the details
//                ('href' and 'text') of the links, stored
//                in properties named for the 'id' of the
//                ancestor elements.
function enableLinks(opts) {
  let settings = {

      // identifying an <a> element with a 'href' attribute
      // set to the value of '#':
      'linkSelector': 'a[href="#"]',
      'linkMap': {
        'CorporateManualPolicies': {
          'href': 'http://example.com/corporate/manual/policies',
          'text': 'Link to Corporate Manual Policies.'
        },
        'stackoverflow': {
          'href': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
          'text': 'Link to Stack Overflow.'
        }
      }
    },

    // declaring 'empty' variables for later use:
    ancestor,
    child,
    cache;

    // here we return the result of the following expression,
    // in which we iterate over the keys of the
    // 'settings.linkMap' Object:
    return Object.keys(settings.linkMap)

    // filtering the keys of that Object:
    .filter(

      // retaining only those keys that result in a
      // truthy value, in that if document.getElementById(key)
      // evaluates to null the key is discarded, if it retrieves
      // an element then it is retained:
      key => document.getElementById(key)

    // iterating over the Array of keys, using
    // Object.prototype.map(), which returns a new Array, usually
    // based on actions taken upon, or properties of, the supplied
    // Array:
    ).map(function(key) {
      // 'key' : a reference to the current key of the Array
      //         of keys over which we're iterating.

      // finding the ancestor using document.getElementById(key)
      // since the properties of the Object are the 'id' of
      // elements - and finding an element with that id was
      // the criteria for retaining any given key - this finds
      // the relevant ancestor element:
      ancestor = document.getElementById(key);

      // retrieving the relevant Object of details for the
      // given descendant element from the settings.linkMap
      // Object:
      cache = settings.linkMap[ key ];

      // finding the relevant descendant element, by passing
      // the settings.linkSelector CSS selector to the
      // the querySelector() method, which returns the first
      // element matching that selector, or null if no element
      // is found:
      child = ancestor.querySelector(settings.linkSelector);

      // if the value of the child variable is truthy (a
      // descendant element was found):
      if (child) {

        // the 'href' property of that element is set to
        // the property-value held in the cache.href property:
        child.href = cache.href;

        // the child.title and child.textContent properties
        // are both set to the property-value of the 
        // cache.text property:
        child.title = child.textContent = cache.text;

        // here we return the child variable to the created
        // Array; because this is enclosed within the
        // if (child) statement the Array.prototype.map()
        // method will return undefined if no child exists:
        return child;
      }

    // because the created Array will be composed of elements
    // and undefined, we use Array.prototype.filter() again
    // this time passing the Boolean constructor as an
    // argument; this function takes a value - here the
    // arguments are passed automatically from
    // Array.prototype.filter, and are the current-value
    // of the Array, the index of the current array-value and
    // a copy of the whole Array; Boolean takes the only the
    // first argument, and returns either true or false
    // depending on that argument. A true or truthy argument
    // results in true, and false or falsey arguments result
    // in false. The returned value of true/false retains
    // or discards the current Array value respectively:
    }).filter(Boolean);

}

// again, calling the function, using the default arguments, and
// iterating over the returned Array of elements to add the
// 'enabledLink' class-name to those found elements:
enableLinks().forEach( el => el.classList.add( 'enabledLink') );
```

```js
    function enableLinks(opts) {
      let settings = {
          'linkSelector': 'a[href="#"]',
          'linkMap': {
            'CorporateManualPolicies': {
              'href': 'http://example.com/corporate/manual/policies',
              'text': 'Link to Corporate Manual Policies.'
            },
            'stackoverflow': {
              'href': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
              'text': 'Link to Stack Overflow.'
            }
          }
        },
        ancestor,
        child,
        cache;

      return Object.keys(settings.linkMap)
        .filter(
          key => document.getElementById(key)
        ).map(function(key) {
          ancestor = document.getElementById(key);
          cache = settings.linkMap[key];
          child = ancestor.querySelector(settings.linkSelector);

          if (child) {
            child.href = cache.href;
            child.title = child.textContent = cache.text;

            return child;
          }
        }).filter(Boolean);

    }

    enableLinks().forEach(el => el.classList.add('enabledLink'));
```

```css
.enabledLink {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.enabledLink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h2>Quality Management Key Documents</h2>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Corporate Manual Policies and User Manual</button>
  <div id="CorporateManualPolicies" class="dropdown-content">
    <button class="page-header">Works?</button>
    <a href="#">Derpalot</a>
  </div>
  <h2>External Resources</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Corporate Manual Policies and User Manual</button>
    <div id="stackoverflow" class="dropdown-content">
      <button class="page-header">Works?</button>
      <a href="#">Derpalot</a>
    </div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jgnxf66j/1/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Boolean` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: Working through this solution now!

Comment: Best of luck! Obviously if there's any problems, issues or questions feel free to leave a comment and I'll respond as soon as I can (though it might be a few hours, given the current UK time) :)

Comment: This works as written in JS Fiddle. Unfortunately when I run it through my webstorm IDE it doesn't output properly. Trying to work it out still.

Comment: The code doesn't use the javascript when going through the IDE so very confused - trying to see if there's any typo's or something o